# How to locate element by partial onclick attribute with single quote in the value?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div style="padding: 4px 15px; background-color: rgb(212, 208, 200); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" onmouseover="hl(this,true);" onmouseout="hl(this,false);" onclick="select_menu('1','doc_107094');">Download...</div></div>
```

I'm trying to click the `onclick` event and match until select_menu('1'
with code

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@onclick 'select_menu('1'')]"));
```

and my error

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'Given xpath expression "//div[starts-with(@onclick 'select_menu('1'')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use escaped double quotes around the `onclick` value

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@onclick, \"select_menu('1'\")]");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'Given xpath expression "//div[starts-with(@onclick 'select_menu('1'')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.'
```

...implies that the **xpath** expression was not a valid one.

---

### Reason

When dealing with xpath the `(` and `'` characters are part of the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) syntax. So you need to exclude them or escape them.

---

### Solution

To locate element by partial *onclick* event attribute you can use the following *xpath* based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*  using `starts-with()`:

  ```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@onclick, 'select_menu')]"));
  ```
- *xpath* using `starts-with()` and `contains()`:

  ```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@onclick, 'select_menu') and contains(@onclick, 'doc')]"));
  ```
- *xpath* using the entire value within *onclick* event:

  ```
  FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@onclick=\"select_menu('1','doc_107094');\"]"));
  ```